# Error wrapping an image in an <a> tag for lightbox

Tags: css, wordpress, lightbox

I'm running a wordpress site that has a thumbnail gallery feature. Each thumb is inside an `<a>` tag so that the full image pops in a lightbox. The problem is that, for some reason, the a zone is behind the image and only 16px high (the thumb is 96 x 96). I can't see anything in the css that is causing this.

[An example of this can be seen here](http://www.pinksandgreen.co.uk/products-page/heavenly-homeware/funky-paper-mache-deer-heads/)

```
<a rev="http://www.pinksandgreen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/WALDE-XC14_1-200x200.png" class="wpscimg" rel="lightbox Funky paper mache deer heads" href="http://www.pinksandgreen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/WALDE-XC14_1.png">
    <img width="96" height="96" src="http://www.pinksandgreen.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/WALDE-XC14_1-96x96.png" class="attachment-gold-thumbnails" alt="WALDE-XC14_1">
</a>
```

I can't seem to do anything to alter the height of the  through HTML or css and it's driving me mad!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, kind of. You can click the whole image, right?

It's because an anchor is by itself an inline element. If you really want it to be as wide/high as the image (the only reason why that's totally necessary is when you want to give styling to the a) let it be an (inline-)block:

```
a.thumbnail-a { display: inline-block; }
/** OR **/
a.thumbnail-a { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this does make the whole area active, but the image sits above the link meaning that the only area I can click on to make the lightbox appear is the 5px left margin. z-index has no impact....

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the size of the links.

```
.wpscimg {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But as with the other suggestion the image sits 'above' the link meaning that the only area I can click on to make the lightbox appear is the 5px left margin.